# What's Self in BitwiseOperationsType?

Tags: swift

What's Self in BitwiseOperationsType? Is it a typealias?

```
protocol BitwiseOperationsType {
    func &(_: Self, _: Self) -> Self
    func |(_: Self, _: Self) -> Self
    func ^(_: Self, _: Self) -> Self
    prefix func ~(_: Self) -> Self

    /// The identity value for "|" and "^", and the fixed point for "&".
    ///
    /// ::
    ///
    ///   x | allZeros == x
    ///   x ^ allZeros == x
    ///   x & allZeros == allZeros
    ///   x & ~allZeros == x
    ///
    class var allZeros: Self { get }
}
```

Comment: From the syntax of it, it appears that the answer to the "is it a typename" question is "yes".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Self is "the type declaring conformance to this protocol". So if you have a class Foo that conforms to BitwiseOperationsType, then & for Foo is defined to take two Foos as arguments.